# Linq to sql monodevelop

Tags: linq-to-sql, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to use linq to sql in monodeveolop when i try to retrieve anything from the table i get that error
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[id], [name]
FROM [test]' at line 1
so any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was with mysql so i changed my database to sqlite and everything is okay now. but still don't know why it doesn't work with mysql.